# Payment processing error after migrating to a new server

Tags: extension, payment-processor, contribution-page, migration

We use the the CiviCRM payment processing extension for Click and Pledge.  We migrated from shared hosting to a virtual server hosting.  After the migration the payment processing is getting an error;

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/XXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/wordpress-civicrm-master/com.clickandpledge.payment.clickandpledge/clickandpledge.php on line 202

The domain name has not changed and the DNS records are pointing to the new server IP address.  It has been several days and the new IP address has gone through the internet.

Any suggestions on how to correct?

Everything else with the migration seems to have worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your new hosting environment doesn't have [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) enabled in their PHP.

Check `phpinfo()` output to verify this.

You may be able to enable this yourself or you may need to request it from your new hosting provider - if you have control of your PHP settings you can do this in `php.ini`, or talk to your provider to have them do it.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found

Comment: Adding the SoapClient corrected the problem.  There was one other server setting that was also needed.  Once these were turned on every runs.